# Keras custom loss function dtype error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy, loss-function

I have a NN that has two identical CNN (similar to Siamese network), then merges the outputs, and intends to apply a custom loss function on the merged output, something like this:

```
     -----------------        -----------------
     |    input_a    |        |    input_b    |
     -----------------        -----------------
     | base_network  |        | base_network  |
     ------------------------------------------
     |           processed_a_b                |
     ------------------------------------------
```

In my custom loss function, I need to break y vertically into two pieces, and then apply categorical cross entropy loss on each piece. However, I keep getting dtype errors from my loss function, e.g.:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy_loss, optimizer=RMSprop())
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
>   sample_weight_mode, **kwargs)
>       909             loss_weight = loss_weights_list[i]
>       910             output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
>   --> 911                                         sample_weight, mask)
>       912             if len(self.outputs) > 1:
>       913                 self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
>       451         # apply sample weighting
>       452         if weights is not None:
>   --> 453             score_array *= weights
>       454             score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))
>       455         return K.mean(score_array)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py
>   in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
>       827       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
>       828         try:
>   --> 829           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
>       830         except TypeError:
>       831           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
>       674       name=name,
>       675       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
>   --> 676       as_ref=False)
>       677 
>       678
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype)
>       739 
>       740         if ret is None:
>   --> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>       742 
>       743         if ret is NotImplemented:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
>       612     raise ValueError(
>       613         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r"
>   --> 614         % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
>       615   return t
>       616
>
> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with
>   dtype float32: 'Tensor("processed_a_b_sample_weights_1:0", shape=(?,),
>   dtype=float32)'

Here is a MWE to reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, merge, Dropout
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np

# define the inputs
input_dim = 10
input_a = Input(shape=(input_dim,), name='input_a')
input_b = Input(shape=(input_dim,), name='input_b')
# define base_network
n_class = 4
base_network = Sequential(name='base_network')
base_network.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(input_dim,), activation='relu'))
base_network.add(Dropout(0.1))
base_network.add(Dense(n_class, activation='relu'))
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)
# merge left and right sections
processed_a_b = merge([processed_a, processed_b], mode='concat', concat_axis=1, name='processed_a_b')
# create the model
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=processed_a_b)

# custom loss function
def categorical_crossentropy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # break (un-merge) y_true and y_pred into two pieces
    y_true_a, y_true_b = tf.split(value=y_true, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    y_pred_a, y_pred_b = tf.split(value=y_pred, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(output=y_pred_a, target=y_true_a) + K.categorical_crossentropy(output=y_pred_b, target=y_true_b) 
    return K.mean(loss)

# compile the model
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy_loss, optimizer=RMSprop())
```

Comment: what line gives you the error?

Comment: Also, Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @GrayCygnus the error comes from the compile line, where the loss function is used the first time.

Comment: ok I see, you are using tensorflow as backend based on your tag. Have you tried with theano instead?

Comment: coud you trace your error to what part of the *function* is the one giving value error? I suspect it is `K.categorical_crossentropy()` which is expecting float64 tensors, and you have float32.

Comment: @GrayCygnus Plz see the updated question. It has to do with weights!

Comment: it seems it comes from the `K.mean()` function call, could you save that to a variable and then return the variable to trace the error better? I mean `foo = K.mean(loss)` and `return foo`, you can comment what you get

Comment: wrote an answer based on what could be your problem, do let me know if it works or does not to follow up

Answer (score 1):

As your error indicates, you are working with `float32` data and it expects `float64`. It is necessary to trace the error to its specific line to know for sure what tensor is to be corrected and to be able to help you better.

However, it *seems* to be related to `K.mean()` method, but `ValueError`s can also be generated by the `K.categorical_crossentropy()` method. Therefore the problem could be with your tensors `loss`, both `y_pred`s or both `y_true`s. Given these scenarios I see two things you could try to solve the problem:

1. You can [cast](https://keras.io/backend/) your tensor(s) (lets assume it is `loss`) to the desired (float64) type like this:

   ```
   from keras import backend as K
   new_tensor = K.cast(loss, dtype='float64')
   ```
2. You can declare you inputs to be of type float64 at the beginning, by passing the parameter `dtype` to the `Input()` call (as suggested in [these](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) examples), like this:

   ```
   input_a = Input(shape=(input_dim,), name='input_a', dtype='float64')
   ```