# "Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backend, loss-function

I'm trying to implement my own loss function with the keras backend.
My loss function is inspired from this article : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865517301666 and compute the cohen Kappa score

```
    eye = K.eye(self.number_of_classes)
    n=2
    class_id = 0
    N = K.sum(((K.argmax(y_true)-class_id)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id])
    class_id = 1
    N += K.sum(((K.argmax(y_true)-class_id)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id])
    class_id = 2
    N += K.sum(((K.argmax(y_true)-class_id)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id])
    # class_id = 3
    # N += K.sum(((K.argmax(y_true)-class_id)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id])

    class_id = 0
    N_hat = K.sum(y_true*eye[class_id])/K.sum(y_true)
    class_id_2 = 0
    D = K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 1
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 2
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # class_id_2 = 3
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])

    class_id = 1
    N_hat = K.sum(y_true*eye[class_id])/K.sum(y_true)
    class_id_2 = 0
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 1
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 2
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # class_id_2 = 3
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])

    class_id = 2
    N_hat = K.sum(y_true*eye[class_id])/K.sum(y_true)
    class_id_2 = 0
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 1
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    class_id_2 = 2
    D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # class_id_2 = 3
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])

    # class_id = 3
    # N_hat = K.sum(y_true*eye[class_id])/K.sum(y_true)
    # class_id_2 = 0
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # class_id_2 = 1
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # class_id_2 = 2
    # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])
    # # class_id_2 = 3
    # # D += K.sum(N_hat*((class_id-class_id_2)**n/(self.number_of_classes-1)**n)*y_pred[:, class_id_2])

    return(K.log(K.mean(N/D)))
```

My function was doing fine when working with a simple LSTM architecture built with an LSTM layer and two Dense layers.

But when I tried to add an input Convolution layer for feature reduction, I faced this error :

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("loss/dense_2_loss/strided_slice:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)'

Which by the way pointed to the 4th line. As suggested in [Keras custom loss function dtype error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111136/keras-custom-loss-function-dtype-error)
I tried to cast `y_true` and `y_pred` to `float64` - which didn't change anything.
I then tried to cast to float64 `y_pred[:, class_id]`, but it just changed the line where the error was pointing at.
Every time I was correcting the error an other one appeared until it pointed to this line:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask) 451 # apply sample weighting 452 if weights is not None: --> 453 score_array *= weights 454 score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx())) 455 return K.mean(score_array)

Does anyone have an idea? I emphasize the fact that my loss function was working properly before adding a Conv2D.

Thanks in advance!

PS : If you have any clue how to make my function clearer without any loop supported by the backend.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? Im trying to do the same thing as you (qwk) but I haven't found a solution..

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to find a solution and gave up on it... Sorry that I can't be of any help.